# Rancher Azure VMs: Waiting for SSH to be available

Tags: azure, ssh, rancher

I’m attempting to create a Node Pool of CentOS VMs and have not been successful. After the VMs are spun up, I get the Rancher error message: "Waiting for SSH to be available… " and eventually it times out after 60 tries. I cannot figure out what the problem is nor can I find anything in the variety of Google searches I’ve tried.

Here are the details of the Azure environment

VPN: 192.168.0.0/16

Rancher VM:

- RancherOS (rancher/server:preview)
- Subnet: 192.168.2.0/29

Node Pool:

- Subnet: 192.168.0.0/24
- OS Image: OpenLogic:CentOS:7.3:latest
- Username: azureuser
- Open Ports: all defaults plus 22/tcp

Comment: To troubleshoot this issue more efficiently, could you show me your steps?